# How to deal with Cannot Execute Boolean

Tags: modifiers

Some times when using a Boolean modifier, it will return the error "Cannot Execute Boolean Operation".

[image: Boolean error example image]

This will often happen with multiple Boolean modifiers.

Here is an [example file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/23512).

What causes this? How can I work around this?

Comment: @zeffii I have updated the question with an example .blend

Comment: @gandalf3 it's hard to know what your intention was, but currently you are performing a boolean using cube.002 twice, shouldn't the 1st or 3rd boolean use cube.001?

Comment: stacking booleans is going to get messy when you can't visually see the result of previous booleans. The whole modifier stack is this additive beast, which you are losing control of.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5140/599

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. i'm trying to add a boolean modifier, to cut a hole in a shape by using a cylinder.
I get: "uncontained hole loop does not share vertices with any face loop" 
"CSG failed, exception Failed to merge holes"

any idea?

Comment: @juFo Not sure.. Is it possible there is some non-manfold topology or something?

Comment: @gandalf3 how can I check this? (I'm a beginner)

Comment: @juFo See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7910/599. Press Ctrl alt shift M in edit mode to select non-manifold geometry.

Comment: @gandalf3 everything looks fine. anyway, thanks for the ctrl+alt+shift+m but I did recreated the object in a different way. that was faster :-)

Comment: Sorry to post in an old threat. But this can happened as happened to me, and couldn't find an explanation. Also get the error with an object with split edges. The object was created with mirror modifier X and Y and for any reason the merge and clipping options didn't make a clean seam in the center of the object. I was trying to create a full aluminum tab by drawing one corner only using the mirror modifier to create the other four corners. Once I closed the gap the Boolean modifier works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess would be the clue that the console window provides upon opening the file:

"...intersecting group is not in or out".

Because you are trying to union a mesh that has already been 'unioned' (cube.002 is the union object on boolean modifiers 1 *and* 3) there are no intersections that the boolean can detect, the faces of the object you are trying to union (cube.002) are directly on top of faces that are already there (the cube.002 previously 'unioned').

If there are no intersecting faces then there is nothing to join. The faces of the mesh to be 'unioned' are neither inside the current mesh not outside of it, they are directly on top of it.

I openly admit this is just my theory based on the error message so I could be wrong. I would presume, based on the objects included in the blend file that this is a simple mistake of using 'cube.002' twice as 'cube.001' isn't used in any of the booleans.

Comment: That was it, thanks. (now how did that happen... :P)

I have had this happen to me before, but it is always possible it is just me screwing up there too. I'll look around and see if I can find some of those old files.

Answer (score 0):

Then the face or object that's being applied with a booean doesn't have enough vertices on it. subdivide the face or use the knife tool to create many edges on that face.... C4our your welcome [image]

Answer (score 0):

It may be, there are missing some faces, from your "Cutter" object.
Turn on the face selection mode (in edit mode -> ctrl+tab) and check for missing faces.